# accessing python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing code that will search twitter for key words and store them in a python dictionary:

```
        base_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?rpp=100&q=4sq.com/'
        query = '7bOHRP'
        url_string = base_url + query
        logging.info("url string = " + url_string)
        json_text = fetch(url_string)
        json_response = simplejson.loads(json_text.content)                                              
        result = json_response['results']
        print "Contents"
        print result
```

The resulting dictionary is :

```
Contents[{
    u 'iso_language_code': u 'en',
    u 'text': u "I'm at Cafe en Seine (40 Dawson Street, Dublin) w/ 2 others. http://4sq.com/7bOHRP",
    u 'created_at': u 'Wed, 06 Oct 2010 23:37:02 +0000',
    u 'profile_image_url': u 'http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/573130785/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg',
    u 'source': u '&lt;a href=&quot;http://foursquare.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;foursquare&lt;/a&gt;',
    u 'place': {
        u 'type': u 'neighborhood',
        u 'id': u '898cf727ca504e96',
        u 'full_name': u 'Mansion House B, Dublin'
    },
    u 'from_user': u 'pkerssemakers',
    u 'from_user_id': 60241195,
    u 'to_user_id': None,
    u 'geo': None,
    u 'id': 26597357992,
    u 'metadata': {
        u 'result_type': u 'recent'
    }
}]
Status: 200 OK
Content - Type: text / html;charset = utf - 8
Cache - Control: no - cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00: 00: 00 GMT
Content - Length: 0
```

How can I access the 'from_user' and what is the 'u' before the key and value?

Comment: `Contents` is not actually a dictionary. It is a list that contains a single dictionary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
result[0][u'from_user']
```

The `u` prefix means that it's a [`unicode`](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/) instead of a `str`.

Answer (score 1):

You access the item ala

```
print Contents['from_user']
```

The 'u' in front of the string indicates that the string is uni-code.

Comment: it would actually be Contents[0]['from_user'] like Ignacio has above... Contents looks to be a list of dictionaries based on the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

note that in Python 3.x you don't need the 'u' before the string 'cause all the string are unicode object...

this can be obtained also in Python 2.x, just put at the top of your code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the item returned is a list containing a dictionary you would do:

```
print Contents[0]['from_user']
```

The u is for unicode and you do not need to mention that when you access the data. Python takes care of that.

Since the data returned is in a dictionary itself the final statement would be

```
print result['Contents'][0]['from_user']
```